# Closest Point on a Sphere to Another Point

Tags: java, geometry, implementation

Given a sphere `S(c,r)`, `c` being the center point `(x,y,z)` and `r` being the radius, there is a point `p(x', y', z')` which is either inside or outside `S`.
I want to find the point `q` such that `q` is on `S` and `|pq|` is minimum. Where `|pq|` denotes the Euclidean distance between `p` and `q`.

I tried to create a ray that starts from `c` and passes through `p` and find the intersection of the ray with the sphere.

However, since I'm implementing a Java code for this problem, I could not get over it with step by step. Could you please help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 3D geometry and not specifically about programming.  Before you can write code you need to have the mathematical algorithm defined and it appears you do not have that yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to normalize the vector `p - c` then multiply by `r` and add `c`.

```
Vector v = p - c; // v.x = p.x - c.x, v.y = p.y - c.y, v.z = p.z - c.z
length = v.length; // = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);
v = v.normalize; //v.x = v.x / length , v.y = v.y / length, v.z = v.z / length
v = v * r // v.x = v.x * r , v.y = v.y * r, v.z = v.z * r
q = v + c // q.x = v.x + c.x, q.y = v.y + c.y, q.z = v.z + c.z
```

Comment: Clean explanation. Commenting as well.